# Bayes theorem usable for Sudoku cell probability?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

With the given Sudoku puzzle, is it possible to apply the Bayes theorem to get the probability of the circled cell being an 8? How much would that be?

[image: sudoku partial solution]

As you can see from the two mayor cells above the number 8 has to be in one of the two minor cells at the far right column in the mayor cell at the bottom.
So that would result in a chance of $\frac{1}{5}$ that the circled cell is an 8, as there are 5 cells unfilled.
Now with the knowledge above, it would be $\frac{1}{2}$. Either an 8 or a different remaining digit.

I solved the puzzle and it's actually the 8. As it felt like it would definitely be the 8 before I even started the puzzle, I'm wondering if chances are actually higher than $\frac{1}{2}$ for the marked cell to be the 8.

Any help/explanation appreciated!

Comment: A  well-posed Sudoku problem should only have one solution so probabilities do not really apply.

Comment: To expand on @Henry's comment, which I think is the correct answer to your question: you could carve out a *part* of a Sudoku puzzle (e.g. just looking at the rightmost three columns) and from that undetermined system ask probabilistic questions. However, the problem you'll always run into when attempting to use Bayes' Theorem is that your fundamental aim is to incorporate more information from the puzzle into the discussion, and it is a truism that with enough information, every cell is completely determined. Thus, I think probability seems like the wrong tool to apply here.